# specflow/use the same random variable in all scenarios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, random, specflow

I have 3 scenarios, in the first i create a user with a random Id. 
and i need to use that SAME random Id in the others scenarios.
I have tried featurecontext to store the Id value. but when i try to put that stored value in a new variable "user" its always null
(I don't have any error msg. the user is created correctly in my REST API, the error msg is at the API level because i serach for a null user)
this is my code

```
Feature
Scenario: Create User
    Given a random user 
    When  I create that user throught the API
            | Field     | Value             |
            | Firstname | Firstname         |
            | Lastname  | Lastname          |   
    Then  the API should returns a "Created" response

Scenario: Check the User-API
    Given the user already created 
    When  i make a Get request of this user
    Then  the API should returns an "OK" response
```

Stepdefinition

```
        [Binding]

            public class CreationUtilisateurSteps
            {
                private string Id;
                private string user;

        [Given(@"a random user)]
                public void GivenARandomUser()
                {
                   id = RandomUtil.GetRandomString();
                   FeatureContext.Current["mystoredid"]=id;
                }

        [When(@"I create that user throught the API")]
            public void WhenICreateThatUserThroughtTheAPI(Table table)
            {
                var user = table.CreateInstance<UserProfile>();
                var client = new RestClient(Settings.Default);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Token", "");
                request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "");
                request.AddHeader("Accept", "");
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "");
                request.AddParameter("undefined", @"
                 {
                 ""id"":""" + Id + @""",
                 ""profile"":
                 {""firstname"":""" + user.Firstname + @""",
                 ""lastname"":""" + user.Lastname + @""",
                 }", ParameterType.RequestBody);

                response = client.Execute(request);
            }

    [Then(@"the API should returns a (.*) response")]
            public void ThenTheAPIShouldReturnsACreatedResponse(string statusCode)
            {
                Assert.Equal(Enum.Parse(typeof(HttpStatusCode), statusCode), response.StatusCode);
                var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);

            }

  [Given(@"the user already created ")]
        public void GivenLUtilisateurDejaCree()
        {
            user=FeatureContext.Current["mystoredid"].tostring();
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: Why would you need (true) random in a test case?  What's wrong with `randomId = 123;` ?

Comment: because there are automated tests and every time I should create a different user with unique string Id. If i use same id=123 for example the API won't create the user and return a bad request with "user already exists"

Comment: The a random value is no good either - there a small but increasing chance of collison.

Comment: Testing should be done with the same (fresh) starting environment. But other options exist, like deleting User123 each time.

Comment: we can't delete a created user . It's API rules ;)

Comment: Still, random is not what you should want here.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using specflow it is not a good idea to rely on test data from one test for another. I find it way too brittle, but maybe that is just me.

That being said, and maybe I am missing something, if the given steps are in the same binding couldn't you change 
`private string id` to `private static string id` so that it is persisted between the tests?

**Update**

Here is an example showing that a static variable will persist between tests:

```
namespace specflow
{
    [Binding]
    public class Class1
    {
        private static string id;

        [Given(@"I have a new user")]
        public void GivenIHaveANewUser()
        {
            id = "5";
        }

        [Given(@"I have the same user")]
        public void GivenIHaveTheSameUser()
        {
            Assert.That(id, Is.EqualTo("5"));
        }
    }
}

Feature: SpecFlowFeature1

Scenario: new user
    Given I have a new user

Scenario: same user
    Given I have the same user
```

**That being said** it seems to me that you have other issues with your acceptance tests. You make it sound like you are not deleting these users after the test is done running. This is fine if you are running against an environment that you do not care about. If you are running against a shared environment or a production environment you have alot of random user sitting around that really should not be. You should really have an `[AfterFeature]` deleting the users from the database.
Also it would be better practice to create and delete a user for each test. That way you are not relying on another test for data your test are therefor less brittle.

Comment: how to do this please

Comment: Change 
`private string id` to `private static string id`

Comment: i already tried this..it access to the same variable but everytime its a different value because is random

Comment: Imho, a test should be able to run on itself, without depending on other tests. So if you need to test the same user, create it and use it in the same test.